# is it necessary for a JsonDeserialize custom bean to be created for each field in object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a custom deserialization class that I am using to make sure that null Doubles are deserialized to null rather than 0.0

```
public class DoubleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Double> {

    @Override
    public Double deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String doubleStr = parser.getText();
        if (doubleStr.isEmpty() || doubleStr == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Double(doubleStr);
    }
}
```

I annotate each fields as such:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleDeserializer.class)
private Double partialPressureCO2;

@JsonDeserialize(using = DoubleDeserializer.class)
private Double partialPressureO2;
```

I have noticed for each field in the bean that a DoubleDeserializer object gets created as it is processed.  This seems very inefficient.  Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: _very inefficient_ is very subjective. Creating an instance is very fast. If you've benchmarked this to be an issue, please demonstrate how.

Comment: I agree re "subjective".  I haven't benchmarked yet - what should I benchmark against?